# Strange symbol at the beginning of the imported CSV file

Tags: java, csv, parsing, export-to-csv

I am parsing one CSV file into my JTable. The problem is that some weird symbol appears in front of my very first record every time. Here is my code:

```
JFileChooser chooser=new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f=chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String filename=f.getAbsolutePath();
    pathF.setText(filename);

    try {
        FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(fr);

        DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        Object [] lines=br.lines().toArray();
        for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
            String []row=lines[i].toString().split(";");
            model.addRow(row);
        }
```

So everything is OK but in front of first record appears strange symbol. Here is the output:
[image: Screenshot of Application with occuring symbols]

As you can see there is empty square in front of i10. For sure this is some character but how can I get rid of it because thanks to this character the program is assuming that i10 and (square)i10 are different persons. I also checked it with `System.out.println(lines[i].toString());` and the result was:
[image]

You can clearly see the unwanted symbol in from of first row. How can I fix it?

Comment: A lot of input, where the real question is a completely different one, and has nothing to do with your java code: what is in that file ;-) dont ask why your java code does something about a character in that file. Ask yourself what that character **really** is (for example by looking at the file using a **hex** editor) and doing some research ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its called a BOM(Byte order Mark). It marks the begining of the stream you can remove it using BOMInputStream of Apache Commons csv library. Use that library to read and parse a csv, its much simpler and provides a lot of features.

Something like this:

```
BOMInputStream bis = new BOMInputStream(file.getInputStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bis,StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Example to use apache commons: https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-write-csv-file-apache-commons-csv/

MOre info on Bom: [How to exclude BOM with BOM InputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136230/how-to-exclude-bom-with-bom-inputstream)

Comment: Yet another good reason to not write your own CSV parser. I wrote one 20 years ago, and I thought I had covered all relevant aspects ... and today I learned that I overlooked something back then ;-)

Comment: Yet another good reason to not use CSV !!!  As a format, it's completely nonstandard and you simply never know what unanticipated encoding tricks anyone using it has been applying.  Does the CSV "standard" either or not support \uxxxx notation to denote any arbitrary BMP character ?  Must comma characters appearing in data values also be "escaped" if the separator in use is the semicolon ?  In fact, does there even exist a standard "escaping" syntax at all in CSV ?  Does it either or not support encoding tricks with overlay characters, say "~n" for representing "ñ" ?  etc. etc. etc.